# Add Marker on click & get lat long differently

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Code for popup onMouseClick, which shows lat & long

```
var popup = L.popup();

    function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(mymap);
    }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

Is it possible to add marker, i tried to put *'marker* in function, but didn't work.

And how to get lat long differently, so i can copy it in two diff variables

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/t4651db3/5/)

Comment: Could you provide a Jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Fiddle here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t4651db3/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the marker directly inside your `onclick` function

```
var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
```

And to get the lat and lng separately you were close

```
var lat = e.latlng.lat;
var lng = e.latlng.lng;
```

Finally, here is your updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4651db3/7/)

Comment: Thank you, but marker is showing when i add another marker. Do  Check and marker shouldn't  be multiple.

Comment: When you click the marker is just hidden by your popup. Click somewhere then close the popup and here is your marker

Comment: Can we show both popup and marker at the same time ?

Comment: @DivyamSolanki Sorry I don't know this. This is a different problem. You should search or ask a new question on SO

Answer (score 0):

**i think you are expecting something like this**

```
function onMapClick(e) {
 new L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).addTo(map).bindPopup("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString()).openPopup();
    }
```

Comment: according to your requirements what i undertood the following solution can be preffered